# Using generics as arguments to a functions inside a collection

Tags: generics, types, rust, traits

I am trying to store several functions inside a HashMap inside a struct. 
It works if I use solid types:

```
extern crate bson;
extern crate serde;

use std::sync::Arc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

type CBack = Fn(Vec<bson::Array>) -> Vec<u8> + Send + Sync + 'static;

struct Struct {
    cback_map: HashMap<String, Arc<CBack>>
}

fn main() {}
```

When I start using generics for the arguments and return type of the closures, the compiler starts to complain about objects not being sized and so on. I want, instead, my map to hold closures with the following signature:

```
fn fun<'de, D, R>(_: D) -> R
   where D: serde::Deserialize<'de>, R: serde::Serialize {}
```

How do I define that map properly?

Comment: _"compiler starts to complain"_ It will be much easier to help if you provide these complaints. :) I also wonder what the main context is, since that last function signature is quite unlike what you mentioned before that.

Comment: I said the compiler starts to complain, because, at first it's about not being sized, them It's about not not being able to specify additional traits with "+" if they are not sync or send, them It's about not being able to use generics in this context, etc. etc.

Comment: You haven't **shown us in your question** what kind of code you have tried that is causing the problem. All you have done is show us code that *works*, then said "if I add in some generics, I get some errors", without showing *how* those generics were added or the exact complete errors that were generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to the map to be heterogeneous, i.e. to hold different versions of the function instantiated with different types, then you will need to change its signature.

For any *given* type `R`, if the type is `Sized`, then this function will work. But for *all possible* `R`s, the compiler cannot know the size because each could be different.

To get that to work, you will need to use a trait object like `Box<Serialize>` or `&Serialize`.

You are also likely to have other problems. But your question and code example are not complete enough to make observations beyond those I have made above, related to "objects not being sized and so on".

Comment: I suppose the box will help, but then comes another problem. Deserialize requires one lifetime parameter, which refers to the arguments of the function. It definitely must not be one shared lifetime across the entire map, that's a leak. Is it possible for the lifetimes to be declared for each function separately?

Comment: _"but then comes another problem"_ — and this is why it is difficult for anyone to help you effectively without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).